# Condicional Expectation when $\mathbb{E}[X] = \infty$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \textit{F}_0, \mathbb{P})$ and $\textit{F} \subset \textit{F}_0$. Suppose $X \geq 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[X] = \infty$. Then there is a unique $Y \textit{F}$-measurable with $0 \leq Y \leq \infty$ so that

\begin{align*}
    \int_A X d\mathbb{P} = \int_A Y d\mathbb{P}
\end{align*}

for all $A \in \textit{F}$

My attempt:

The book from where I took this exercise gives a hint: Let $X_M = X ∧ M$.

Then I can consider $Y_M = \mathbb{E}[X_M | \textit{F} ]$. 
I know that $X_M \uparrow X$, so I would like this to happen: $Y_M \uparrow \mathbb{E}[X | \textit{F}]$. I tried to use the Monotone Convergence Theorem, but I do not have that $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$ (I have the opposite haha).

Comment: I don't think that the Monotone Convergence Theorem requires $X$ to be integrable.

Comment: It requires. It is written in the same as the exercise.

Comment: What I mean is that there can be another version, but I am not supposed to use it.